# Specific IP and PORT traffic change to another IP and PORT

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

On one machine I have two local IP addresses, I need to make iptables rule to:

Forward 192.168.1.10:80 traffic to be forwarded to specific IP and PORT 192.168.1.11:8080

I tried without any success

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.11
```

Comment: Did you set > net.ipv4.ip_forward to 1?

Comment: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

Comment: @A.B Its ubuntu machine, regular installation. with netplan i created additional network interface and that's it. Im new to networking so if you have some questions just please can you make it more clear ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were close. Your destination port (--dport) should be 80 then you can use the colon notation for the forward specification

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.11:8080
```